# How to implement Master-Detail component in the community edition of the react ag-grid? Open sub-component on click of expand/collapse icon

Tags: ag-grid-react

Master-Detail view or component is available in enterprise version only. Due to some constraints, I can't buy a license. Is there any possibility of implementing Master-Detail view, where subcomponent will open on click of expand or collapse icon?

I want to implement react ag-grid Master Detail feature. However, it is an enterprise level feature, and I am currently using the community version. Is there any other way to achieve this?